# Rails: Duplicate validation error messages only in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I am using [phonelib](https://github.com/daddyz/phonelib) gem for phone number validation.
In my user model, `user.rb` I have

```
validates :phone, phone: { allow_blank: true, message: "Please enter valid contact number" }
```

In `_form.html.erb`

```
<%= f.number_field :phone, :maxlength => '16', class: 'phone-number' %>
<%= f.error_message_on :phone %>
```

When a user enters invalid phone number I am getting the error message *"Please enter valid contact number"* twice.
[image]

Also I have another validation

```
validates_presence_of :company_type, message: 'Please enter your company type'
```

and in my partial

```
<%= f.select :company_type, [], { prompt: false }, class: 'company-type' %>
<%= f.error_message_on :company_type %>
```

[image]

The strange thing is **this happens only in production** and not in development environment. Can anyone help me figure out what is causing this behaviour? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could try to start up your rails server in production environment and track this bug down

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check whether this link helps you in getting rid of the bug. since your entire code was not there above.

[Errors are displayed twice in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29038232/errors-are-displayed-twice-in-rails)